# pandas performance: columns selection

Tags: pandas

I've observed today that selecting two or more columns of Data frame may be much slower than selecting only one.

If I use loc, or iloc to choose more than one column and I use list to pass column names or indexes, then performance drops 100 times in comparison to single column or many column selection with iloc (but no list passed)

examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10**7,10), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
```

One column selection:

```
%%timeit -n 100
df['b']
3.17 µs ± 147 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n 100
df.iloc[:,1]
66.7 µs ± 5.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n 100
df.loc[:,'b']
44.2 µs ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Two columns selection:

```
%%timeit -n 10
df[['b', 'c']]
96.4 ms ± 788 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n 10
df.loc[:,['b', 'c']]
99.4 ms ± 4.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n 10
df.iloc[:,[1,2]]
97.6 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Only this selection works like expected:
[EDIT]

```
%%timeit -n 100
df.iloc[:,1:3]
103 µs ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

What are the differences in mechanisms and why they are so big?

[EDIT]:
As @run-out pointed out, pd.Series seems to be processed much faster than pd.DataFrame, anyone knows why it is the case?

On the other hand - it does not explain difference between `df.iloc[:,[1,2]]` and `df.iloc[:,1:3]`

Comment: You're selecting only one column in `df.iloc[:, 1:2]`

Comment: I would imagine that it has to do with `loc` and `iloc` slicing rows and columns. That is why if you use the `[]` operator to slice rows before using the `[]` operator to slice columns you get similar results to `loc` and `iloc`: `df[:]['b']` I also imagine that the time difference has to do with if you are returning a Series or a DataFrame

Comment: @MohitMotwani thanks, corrected, does not change the result though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pandas works with single rows or columns as a pandas.Series, which would be faster than working within the DataFrame architecture.

Pandas works with pandas.Series when you ask for:

```
%%timeit -n 10
df['b']
2.31 µs ± 1.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

However, I can call a DataFrame for the same column by putting it in a list. Then you get:

```
%%timeit -n 10
df[['b']]
90.7 ms ± 1.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

You can see from the above that it's the Series that is outperforming the DataFrame.

Here is how Pandas is working with column 'b'.

```
type(df['b'])
pandas.core.series.Series

type(df[['b']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

EDIT:
I'm expanding on my answer as OP wants to dig deeper into why there is greater speed is so much greater for pd.series vs. pd.dataframe. And also as this is a great question to expand my/our understanding of how the underlying technology works. Those with more expertise please chime in.

First let's start with numpy as it's a building block of pandas. According to Wes McKinney, author of pandas and from Python for Data Analysis, the performance pick up in numpy over python:

```
This is based partly on performance differences having to do with the
cache hierarchy of the CPU; operations accessing contiguous blocks of memory (e.g.,
summing the rows of a C order array) will generally be the fastest because the mem‐
ory subsystem will buffer the appropriate blocks of memory into the ultrafast L1 or
L2 CPU cache.
```

Let's see the speed difference for this example. Let's make a numpy array from column 'b' of the dataframe.

```
a = np.array(df['b'])
```

And now do the performance test:

```
%%timeit -n 10
a
```

The results are:

```
32.5 ns ± 28.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

That's a serious pick up in performance over the pd.series time of 2.31 µs.

The other main reason for performance pickup is that numpy indexing goes straight into NumPy C extensions, but there is a lot of python stuff going on when you index into a Series, and this is a lot slower. ([read this article](https://penandpants.com/2014/09/05/performance-of-pandas-series-vs-numpy-arrays/))

Let's look at the question of why does:

```
df.iloc[:,1:3]
```

drastically outperform:

```
df.iloc[:,[1,2]]
```

It's interesting to note that .loc has the same effect with performance as .iloc in this scenario.

Our first big clue that something is not right is in the following code:

```
df.iloc[:,1:3] is df.iloc[:,[1,2]]
False
```

These give the same result, but are different objects. I've done a deep dive try to find out what the difference is. I was unable to find reference to this on the internet or in my library of books.

Looking at the source code, we can start to see some difference. I refer to indexing.py.

In the Class _iLocIndexer we can find some extra work being done by pandas for list in an iloc slice.

Right away, we run into these two difference when checking input:

```
if isinstance(key, slice):
            return
```

vs.

```
elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
            # check that the key does not exceed the maximum size of the index
            arr = np.array(key)
            l = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))

            if len(arr) and (arr.max() >= l or arr.min() < -l):
                raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
```

Could this alone be cause enough for the reduced performance? I don't know.

Although .loc is slightly different, it also suffers performance when using a list of values. Looking in index.py, look at def _getitem_axis(self, key, axis=None):    --> in class _LocIndexer(_LocationIndexer):

The code section for is_list_like_indexer(key) that handles list inputs is quite long including a lot of overhead. It contains the note:

```
# convert various list-like indexers
# to a list of keys
# we will use the *values* of the object
# and NOT the index if its a PandasObject
```

Certainly there is enough additional overhead in dealing with a list of values or integers then direct slices to cause delays in processing.

The rest of the code is past my pay grade. If anyone can have a look and chime it, it would be most welcome

Comment: This a great situation where it is very wise to know what objects you are working with, pd.Series or pd.Dataframe, or maybe even a np.array at times.  Use `type`, ie... `type(df['b'])`, `type(df[['b']])` etc...  +1  Good answer @run-out

Comment: Thanks, this answers part of my question, but let me go deeper - why series is so much faster? Also the question about differences in "two columns selection" remains

Comment: Nice answer;) don't know why I didn't check the source code.
Did I understand correctly, that all the difference between pd.Series and DataFrame might be sitting in additional indexes and metadata? 

I accepted the answer though I still hope for someone to continue the explanation;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, but I don't have enough experience to give a better answer. I would also like to know. But in looking at the code, there did seem to be quite a bit of additional handling for lists, and it would seem reasonable to me that accounts for the performance drop. I'm still not sure about the objects not being equal, that one has me confused.  (df.iloc[:,1:3] is df.iloc[:,[1,2]]
False

Comment: Actually the part with the np.array is misleading. By calling  `%%timeit -n 10
a`, it's being read from memory, while calling `df['b']` creates pd.Series.
See this: `a = df['b']`, `b = np.array(df['b'])`, for both `a` and `b` it takes the same  time to read in (in my case 16 ns). Which makes sense for me, because pd.Series is basically np.array (+metadata). What's more: `c=df[['a','b']]', ``%%timeit c` gives 17.9 ns ± 0.0663 ns per loop, which is only slightly more. DataFrame is probably still only array under the hood

Answer (score 4):

I found this probably rooted in numpy.

numpy has two kind of indexing:

1. basic indexing like a[1:3]
2. advanced indexing like a[[1,2]]

according to the documentation,

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with
>   basic slicing that returns a view).

So if you check

```
a=df.values
%timeit -n2 a[:,0:3]
%timeit -n2 a[:,[0,1,2]]
```

you got

```
The slowest run took 5.06 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1.57 µs ± 1.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2 loops each)
188 ms ± 2.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2 loops each)
```

quite similar behavior to pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend using the cudf library, it is basically pandas ported on Nvidia GPU. It is extremely fast as most operations are highly parallelized contrary to pandas.
You need to have a Nvidia GPU available tough, starting from generation GTX 10xx.

Columns slicing is extremely fast, I'll come with benchmarks when I have time.