# multiIndex slicing performance issue

Tags: python, pandas, performance

define pandas dataframe like below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n=1000
x=np.repeat(range(n),n)
y=np.tile(range(n),n)
z=np.random.random(n*n)
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y,'z':z})
df=df.set_index(['x','y']).sort_index()
idx=pd.IndexSlice
```

then some index slicing timing

```
%timeit -n100 df.loc[idx[1],:]
%timeit -n100 df.loc[idx[1,1],:]
%timeit -n100 df.loc[idx[1:10],:]
%timeit -n100 df.loc[idx[1:10,1],:]
```

gives

```
361 µs ± 53.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
164 µs ± 1.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
165 µs ± 8.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.35 ms ± 51.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can see, **`df.loc[idx[1:10,1],:]` takes much much more times which seems like a performance bug. What is wrong here?**

On the other hand, though it is said that pandas index is hashed. But indexing is far slower than dict.

Let's prepare a somewhat equivalent dict

```
d={i:{k:k for k in range(n)} for i in range(n)}
```

and similar timing

```
%timeit -n100 d[1]
%timeit -n100 d[1][1]
%timeit -n100 [d[i] for i in range(10)]
%timeit -n100 [d[i][1] for i in range(10)]
```

gives

```
36.3 ns ± 3.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
52.7 ns ± 3.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
811 ns ± 7.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.02 µs ± 79.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Wow, 1000 times faster than pandas indexing! **Why pandas index slicing is so slow?**

Comment: The API is doing 10,000 things when you call `.loc`, plus you'd have to factor in the time it takes to create the result df. OTOH indexing a dict inside a list comprehension is so fast because it has direct code paths in C, it is like apples and oranges.

Comment: @cs95 Thank you so much for comment. Then what about `df.loc[idx[1:10,1],:]` ? why it is so slower than others

Comment: The answer is very likely to be a boring implementation detail that you'd find only by digging into the source (disclaimer: it's quite vast). You may just as well ask why `df.loc[idx[1],:]` is slower than `df.loc[idx[1, 1],:]`, there's really not much to glean from this. If you need performance, you should probably stick to dicts.

Comment: @cs95 OK, but it looks like a implementation performance bug.

Comment: I tackled a similar question a while ago. Might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767327/pandas-performance-columns-selection/54768379#54768379

Comment: @run-out Thank you so much for metioning this post. I am shocked by the timing in that post. Looks like another performance bug:) BTW, the problem in that post seems somewhat different from my post. It is a timing difference between slice `df.loc[:,'b':'c']` and explict list `df.loc[:,['b','c']]` in that post. But in my post, there is only slice

Comment: Agreed. I just thought the parralels might be of interest.

Comment: @run-out I just post an answer on the post you mentioned. Take a look at it :)