# pandas eval, return dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In pandas [eval documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) it states that a dataframe is a possible return; however, there aren't any examples of how to do this. I am trying come up with a faster way to [select several columns more quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767327/pandas-performance-columns-selection) and I thought eval might be advantageous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this example at the end of [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html)

[image]

Comment: fair enough, that answers the question I asked even if it wasn't what I was looking for

Comment: In this link I see a lot more examples for eval. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#enhancingperf-eval